# How to delete tags from xml

Tags: linux, text-processing, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<deviceID>IO238470374109730497</devicdeID>
<KeyValuePairs>
    <KeyValuePair>
      <BASE-URL>2</BASE-URL>
      <Key>2</Key>
      <Value>2</Value>
    </KeyValuePair>
    <KeyValuePair>
     <BASE-URL>3</BASE-URL>
     <Key>3</Key>
     <Value>3</Value>
   </KeyValuePair>
</KeyValuePairs>
```

I want to delete only this section:

```
<KeyValuePair>
    <BASE-URL>3</BASE-URL>
    <Key>3</Key>
    <Value>3</Value>
</KeyValuePair>
```

What I want to achieve is to delete what is inside and including `<KeyValuePair>` only for these specific `<BASE-URL>`, `<Key>` and `<Value>`. The `<KeyValuePair>` tuple is always unique and won't be repeated, but it can be one or more.

How can I do that using bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example isn't a valid XML file. I've altered it slightly by adding a `<root/>` element surrounding the document (and fixing your typo in the closing `</deviceID>` marker):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <deviceID>IO238470374109730497</deviceID>
    <KeyValuePairs>
        <KeyValuePair>
            <BASE-URL>2</BASE-URL>
            <Key>2</Key>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
        <KeyValuePair>
            <BASE-URL>3</BASE-URL>
            <Key>3</Key>
            <Value>3</Value>
        </KeyValuePair>
    </KeyValuePairs>
</root>
```

Now it's possible to use an XML editing tool to edit your XML. This XPath expression tells `xmlstarlet` to delete the XML element `<KeyValuePair/>` (and its content) where `<BASE-URL/>` has a text value `3`.

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//KeyValuePair[BASE-URL/text()="3"]' /tmp/500185.xml
```

And the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <deviceID>IO238470374109730497</deviceID>
  <KeyValuePairs>
    <KeyValuePair>
      <BASE-URL>2</BASE-URL>
      <Key>2</Key>
      <Value>2</Value>
    </KeyValuePair>
  </KeyValuePairs>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works! How about doing this as a shell script? I also want to make another script to read the values in `<Value>` and call a curl command to their `<BASE-URL>`

Comment: `xmlstarlet` is a command you can call from a shell script, just like `sed` or `awk` or `grep`. There are lots of examples for `xmlstarlet` here on [Unix.SE] and also on the other [SE] sites. (I've written some of them.)